# Why doesn't Docker Hub cache Automated Build Repositories as the images are being built?

Tags: docker

**Note**: It appears the premise of my question is no longer valid since the **new Docker Hub appears to support caching**. I haven't personally tested this. See the [new answer below](https://stackoverflow.com/a/53946127/665224).

Docker Hub's Automated Build Repositories don't seem to cache images. As it is building, it removes all intermediate containers. Is this the way it was intended to work or am I doing something wrong? It would be really nice to not have to rebuild everything for every small change. I thought that was supposed to be one of the best advantages of docker and it seems weird that their builder doesn't use it. So why doesn't it cache images?

UPDATE:
I've started using [Codeship](https://www.codeship.io) to build my app and then run remote commands on my DigitalOcean server to copy the built files and run the docker build command. I'm still not sure why Docker Hub doesn't cache.

Comment: I'm not sure why this question is getting downvoted, because its very annoying when Docker-Hub itself doesn't use the unique and publicized caching feature of Docker itself...

Comment: Maybe because a Dockerfile command like "RUN git clone ..." would need to be run every time, and could never rely on a cached image?

Comment: I would think that that would cache because it is a RUN command and not an ADD but i could be wrong. I only used ADDs after installing packages and when I was using it it didn't seem to cache anything

Comment: This single feature-lack is what keeps me from using Automated Build Repos. I can build a new image after some code commits on my local machine or build box in seconds thanks to cache. If I do the same with automated builds, it takes close to 30 minutes waiting for all my dependencies to get rebuilt.

Comment: can we have a look at the Dockerfile and the docker build options you're using?

Answer (score 26, accepted):

Disclaimer: I am a lead software engineer at Quay.io, a private Docker container registry, so this is an educated guess based on the same problem we faced in our own build system implementation.

Given my experience with Dockerfile build systems, I would suspect that the Docker Hub does not support caching because of the way caching is implemented in the Docker Engine. Caching for Docker builds operates by comparing the commands to be run against the existing layers found in memory.

For example, if the Dockerfile has the form:

```
FROM somebaseimage
RUN somecommand
ADD somefile somefile
```

Then the Docker build code will:

1. Check to see if an image matching `somebaseimage` exists
2. Check if there is a local image with the command `RUN somecommand` whose parent is the previous image
3. Check if there is a local image with the command `ADD somefile somefile` + a hashing of the *contents* of `somefile` (to make sure it is invalidated when `somefile` changes), whose parent is the previous image

If any of the above steps match, then that command will be skipped in the Dockerfile build process, with the cached image itself being used instead. However, the one key issue with this process is that it requires the cached images to be **present on the build machine**, in order to find and verify the matches. Having **all** of *everyone's* images on build nodes would be highly inefficient, making this a harder problem to solve.

At Quay.io, we solved the caching problem by creating a variation of the Docker caching code that could precompute these commands/hashes and then ask our registry for the cached layers, downloading them to the machine only after we had found the most efficient caching set. This required significant data model changes in our registry code.

If you'd like more information, we gave a technical overview into how we do so in this talk: https://youtu.be/anfmeB_JzB0?list=PLlh6TqkU8kg8Ld0Zu1aRWATiqBkxseZ9g

Comment: I'll have to check that out. I've been using quay.io to host images after I build them because it has a number of great features that Docker Hub didn't have. I'll look into building it on quay.io again. I created a build pipeline that didn't use it and haven't looked at it again. Sounds like you've found a great solution to the problem and done it well. My one question is where do you see quay.io fitting into a build pipeline? Should it take the place of something like Travis or Codeship or would the image building on quay.io occur afterwards using some exported build artifact?

Comment: Not sure why the downvote. That answered clearly for me why Docker Hub might struggle to implement caching even though one of Docker's biggest features is fast builds using caching. I like that he presented other solutions (which may be biased but they are the only ones I've heard of)

Comment: Really depends on how your continuous deployment operates. If you run full integration tests before you produce a binary, then you might simply have Travis or Codeship push to your registry after the building and testing completes. Alternatively, you could have Quay.io build your image, then initiate testing via a webhook call, tagging the image once complete. We, ourselves, have our full unit test suite run *as part of the Dockerfile build*, which allows us to ensure no untested image ends up in production.

Answer (score 3):

The new Docker Hub came out with a new Automated Build system that supports Build Caching.

https://blog.docker.com/2018/12/the-new-docker-hub/